# How to enable sudo privileges for user group to apt-get install anything

Tags: sudo, group, privileges

I want to give a group permission to install software without needing to input a root/sudo password. I'm on Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon.

I have created a group called "basicsudo".

I first typed

```
$ which apt-get  
/usr/bin/apt-get
```

Then

```
sudo visudo
```

then I added the following line

`%basicsudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get install`

to `/etc/sudoers.tmp`

```
[...]
# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

%basicsudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get install
# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I assigned the group to a user by using the `Groups and Users` GUI from the menu. To check this I've run

```
$ groupname Alice 
Alice, basicsudo
```

from my account.

When logged in as Alice, this is confirmed

```
$ groups
Alice, basicsudo
```

But when trying to execute the following line as Alice, I do not succeed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip  
[sudo] password for Alice:           
Sorry, user Alice is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/apt-get    install python3-pip' as root on computername.
```

So clearly a) I'm prompted for a password and b) I can't execute it despite entering a password.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: How did you add Alice to the `groupname` group? Where exactly did you add the lines you show under "I assigned the group to a user."?

Comment: Thanks. And what is the output of `groups` when you are logged in as Alice?

Comment: @terdon Output is the same as `groupname Alice` from my root account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
%basicsudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get install
```

to

```
%basicsudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get install *
```

---

From `man sudoers`:

> A command name is a fully qualified file name which may include shell-style wildcards...  A simple file name allows the user to run the command with any arguments they wish.  However, you may also specify command line arguments (in‐cluding wildcards).  Alternately, you can specify "" to indicate that the command may only be run without command line arguments...
>
> If a Cmnd has associated command line arguments, then the arguments in the Cmnd must match exactly those given by the user on the command line (or match the wildcards if there are any)...

So:

| Sudoers | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `%basicsudo ALL= /usr/bin/apt-get ""` | run `apt-get` with no args |
| `%basicsudo ALL= /usr/bin/apt-get` | run `apt-get` with any args |
| `%basicsudo ALL= /usr/bin/apt-get install` | run `apt-get install` with no more args |
| `%basicsudo ALL= /usr/bin/apt-get install *` | run `apt-get install` with more args |